# Green's function for periodic BVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem**. Determine the *Green's function* for the boundary-value problem
\begin{align}
y^{\prime\prime}(t)=&-f(t)\notag\\
y(-1)=&y(1)\notag\\
y^{\prime}(-1)=&y^{\prime}(1).\notag
\end{align}
**Note**. When I'm solving this problem, I get contradiction from the second boundary condition and the jump type discontinuity condition. Thus, **cannot** obtain the *Green's function*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### General Observations

Since $y'(1)-y'(-1)=-\int_{-1}^{1} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$, we must assume $\int_{-1}^{1} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=0$, otherwise there is no solution. Once this assumption is made, there is no need to worry about  $y'(-1)= y'(1)$ anymore; it will be automatically satisfied.

Also, observe that if $y$ is a solution, then so is $y+c$, where $c$ is any constant. In particular, $y(x)-y(0)$ is also a solution.

Thus, you can use Green's function $g$ for the zero boundary conditions $y(0)=0=y(1)$: the general solution of the given problem is 
$$y(x) = c+\int_{-1}^1 g(x,t) f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$

#### Modified Green's function

The above is what I would do if the goal was to actually find $y$. But you are asked to find Green's function. When differential operator $\mathcal{L}$ has zero eigenvalue (as is the case here, since $\mathcal{L}1=0$), **modified** Green's function is used:
$$\mathcal L g(x,t)=\delta_{t}+c\phi$$
where $\phi$ is an eigenfunction for zero eigenvalue, and $c$ is chosen so that $g$ exists. In our case, $\phi$ is constant, and   $c\phi\equiv -1/2$, because the boundary conditions force 
$$\int_{-1}^1 (\delta_t+c\phi)=0 $$
So, look for 
$$
-\partial^{2}_{x} g(x,t)=\delta_{t}-1/2
$$
which amounts to fitting general pattern $g(x,t) = -\frac12|x-t|+\frac14 x^2+bx$ to the boundary conditions.

(I'll say that this looks more laborious than the approach in the first half.)

More  explanations on [page 53 here](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~wparnell/MT34032_2013/greens_notes.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

You can test for the existence of a Green's function. One way to do it is to check the unforced homogeneous problem, namely, 
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime\prime}=0\\
y\left(1\right)-y\left(-1\right)=0\\
y^{\prime}\left(1\right)-y^{\prime}\left(-1\right)=0
\end{equation}
to see if it only admits the trivial solution.

A general solution is of the form, $y=Ax+B$. Boundary conditions impose that 
$A=0$ and $B$ can be any arbitrary nonzero constant. This means there exists a nontrivial solution to the completely homogeneous problem. Then there cannot be a Green's function.

As user147263 has pointed out, certain solvability condition must be satisfied. You can also get this solvability condition via Fredholm Alternative (FA). Once you found the solution to the adjoint problem (as part of the procedures to get the solvability condition via FA), you can construct the modified Green's function the same way as user147263 said.

My reference is from Stakgold BVP for mathematical physics Volume I.